# Internal JSON-RPC error with Etheriem MetaMask

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, blockchain, metamask

I am making the blockchain local application with Ganache.

I made the file `SingleNumRegister.sol`

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.10;
contract SingleNumRegister{
    struct StoreNumber {
        address from;
        uint256 number;
    }
    StoreNumber[] public storeNumbers;
    function set(uint256 num) public {
        storeNumbers.push(StoreNumber(msg.sender,num));
    }
    function get() public view returns (uint256){
        uint256 index = storeNumbers.length - 1;
        return storeNumbers[index].number;
    }

}
```

`yarn truffle build`
`yarn truffle deploy`
then deploy successfully `/build/contracts/SingleNumRegister.json`

Now I made the file

index.vue

```
<template>

<div class="container">
<div class="links">

<input type="text" v-model="inputNumber" placeholder="input number">
<button @click="setNumber()">
Set Number to contract</button>
</div>
<div class="links">
<button @click="getNumber()">
Get Number to contract
</button>
</div>
<div>
Number:{{number}}
</div>

  <!--Tutorial/-->

</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data(){
    return {
      number:0,
      inputNumber:0
    }
  },
  methods:{
    getNumber: async function(){
      let ret = await this.$contract.methods.get().call()
      this.number = ret
    },
    setNumber: async function(){
      let accounts = await this.$web3.eth.getAccounts()
      let account = accounts[0]
      let ret = await this.$contract.methods.set(this.inputNumber).send({from:account})
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    console.log('CurrentBlock Number')
    this.$web3.eth.getBlockNumber().then(console.log)
  },
  name: 'IndexPage'
}
</script>
```

plugin/web3.js

```
import Web3 from "web3"
import artifacts from "~~/build/contracts/SingleNumRegister.json"

export default async function(context,inject){

    let web3;
    if (typeof window != 'undefined' && typeof window.ethereum != 'undefined'){
        web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum)
        window.ethereum.enable().catch((error) =>{
            console.log(error)
        })
    }else if (
        typeof window !== 'undefined' &&
        typeof window.web3 !== 'undefined'
    ){
        web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider)
    }else {
        const httpEndpoint = "http://127.0.0.1:7545"
        const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(httpEndpoint))
        inject('web3',web3)
    }
    let networkId = await web3.eth.net.getId()
    let contract = new web3.eth.Contract(
        artifacts.abi,
        artifacts.networks[networkId].address
    )
    inject('web3',web3)
    inject('contract',contract)
}
```

When accessing localhost:3000, connection with metamask works well.

However this error comes when I try to use `getNumber` button.

Any help appreciated.

```
Internal JSON-RPC error. { "message": "VM Exception while processing transaction: revert", "code": -32000, "data": { "0x8f56359e693163e3ccde22d45f459ebd6288b4ebd2583e9334fb44cd3602f149": { "error": "revert", "program_counter": 799, "return": "0x4e487b710000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011" }, "stack": "RuntimeError: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert\n at Function.RuntimeError.fromResults (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/lib/utils/runtimeerror.js:94:13)\n at /Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/lib/blockchain_double.js:568:26", "name": "RuntimeError" } }
```